# How to enable pinch-zoom only when both touches are in the same pane

Tags: javascript

I have a page with several panes (see snapshot1 below). I want to restrict pinch-zoom only to specific panes (e.g. A, B)

Currently, I control the pinch-zoom with css touch-action, and user-scalable=no.
But I'm not sure that I'm doing it right. Here is what I do. I,

- place user-scalable=no at the top of the html page (see snippet1)
- populate "touch-action: none" in divs where I want to disable pinch-zoom
- populate "touch-action: pinch-zoom" in divs where I want to enable pinch-zoom

But every so often I find another edge case where the zoom is enabled where it shouldn't be.

Also, I want to **restrict the zoom to only when both touches are in the same pane** (e.g. A).

Currently, if one touch is in pane A, and the other in pane B, both panes A, and B zoom.
This happens in a device with small display area, where many times the user touches 2 panes while pinching and zooming.
This results in both panes zooming, which is confusing to the user.

**My questions are:**

1. What is the correct way to disable pinch-zoom everywhere except for specific divs
2. For areas where zoom is enabled, how to enable zoom, only if both fingers start touching in the same area (div)

Thanks

---

**snapshot1** - image with multiple panes
[image: snapshot1 - image with multiple panes]

**snippet1** - controlling the pinch-zoom with css touch-action, and user-scalable=no

```
cat index.html
...
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
...
```

---

```
cat main.css
...
#navbar1{
    touch-action: none;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use [event.targetTouches.length](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touch_targettouches.asp) to detect and discard cases where the touches are not both starting in the same DOM element.